# How to add hour to date

Tags: bash, date

I am trying to get the date with a variable year, month and day but an specific hour.

Let me explain myself. I have a variable called ***$date*** using the next format

```
date=$(date +%Y%m%d)
```

Which gives me 20130814 (for today). Just as I want for that variable

But I need another variable, let's call it ***$date1*** who will have something like ***$date*** but an specific hour. I mean, taking the example above, 2013081405. I need to add that ***05*** to ***$date*** every single day, that means that for tomorrow I will have 2013081505 and so on

Comment: You should probably mention what programming language you are using.

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: Is a shell script in Linux

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `bash` syntax for that would be:

```
date1="$(date +%Y%m%d)05"
```

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you try

```
$date1 = $date."05";
```

Comment: I tried `date=$(date +%Y%m%d) (new line)$date1 = $date."05"; (new line) echo "date1: '$date1'"` and got this as output `date1: ''`

Comment: This I did it according to php. Which language are you using? This can be taken as a hint, even though its not in php

Comment: Just append 05 to date variable.

Comment: You were really close, none the less this is not php, it's all shell. I specified it in my original question's comments. Thank you anyways, now I know how to do it in php